# How to make a search bar a capsule shape

Tags: html, css

I want to make a search bar a capsule shape instead of the regular rectangle shape search bars usually are when you make them. I have provided the code I have created so far:

```css
#search {
    border: none;
    padding: 10 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <!-- <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span> -->
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search...">
</form>
```

I am expecting a search bar which is shaped like a typical capsule shape so it is flat at the top and bottom but rounded at the left and right. Have tried looking at buttons through W3schools article.

Comment: Did you look at `border-radius`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn on the border, for example ->
`border: 1px solid`
and use the `border-radius` property more than 50% of the search bar height for example ->

```css
#search {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 22px;
}
```